# How to invoke a method in @SessionScoped bean from @ApplicationScoped bean

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-6

is there a way I could get a reference to a @SessionScoped bean and invoke a method on it from an @ApplicationScoped bean?

`BeanManager.getContext()` works during a request, but it looks like outside of a request it doesn't. I keep a list of active HttpSessions in `GlobalHttpSessionController`, but that doesn't seem to be of any help. Thank you for your comments.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyAppScopedClass {

    @Inject
    GlobalHttpSessionController globalHttpSessionController;

    @Inject
    BeanManager beanManager;

    public void updateSessions() {
        // List of active user sessions
        List<HttpSession> session = globalHttpSessionController.getSessions();
        Set<Bean<?>> set = beanManager.getBeans(UserSessionBean.class);

        for (Bean bean : set) {
            ((UserSessionBean) beanManager.getContext(bean.getScope()).get(bean, beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean))).method();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do. Have you given any thought to how this would work correctly if your application is distributed across two or more servers?

Comment: I understand this would not scale. Yes, I am trying to somehow implement global events.

Comment: You might try the Java EE event handling mechanism in [javax.enterprise.event](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/event/package-summary.html).

Comment: @SteveC, unfortunately the CDI events don't work from ApplicationScoped to SessionScoped.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to mimic Spring MVC. When you inject a `SessionScoped` bean in a singleton scoped bean, it injects a proxy that on execution uses the bean in current session. Because without that, you get one bean at the time of creation of the application scoped bean and only access that one.

Edit :

It looks that it is not really easy to extract a session bean out of its context (that is when its session is not active). So you should store a reference to the bean as a session attribute to be able to easily retrieve it later.

But I think what you want is event management. Unfortunately, I never used that in Java EE CDI environment.

Comment: I'm afraid one instance of the `SessionScoped` bean would not be enough. I would like to get all of them without initiating a request.

Comment: @grapa : if you want to keep a list of active sessions, you need a `HttpSessionListener` : you create the bean in the `onCreate` event and store it in the application scoped bean, and remove it in the `onDestroy` event.

Comment: Thanks @Serge, but the problem here is to notify the sessions, when I already have them.

Comment: @grapa : if the bean is stored as a session attribute can't you get it with `session.getAttribute("beanName")` ? (I'm more used to Spring where session scoped beans are stored as session attributes by default)

Comment: When storing the SessionScoped beans during their creation, I can access them later from the ApplicationScoped bean. I guess I would have to check, if these cdi beans got passivated or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instance<> to access beans in a lower scope. Your Application scoped bean will contain a supplier for the Session scoped bean and you access it only when required. You will then get the bean instance of the session in that moment.

```
@Inject
private Instance<MySessionScopedBean> beanInstance;

public void doStuff() {
   beanInstance.get().useMethodOfSessionScopedBean();
}
```

Comment: That is very interesting, but I need to call the method outside of a user request (Actually the most suitable would be to execute the method during a web service call). Active user sessions exist at that moment. If I inject the reference like you suggest, it ends in a `No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` Exception